# Grafana Loki logging problem in .NET Web API - cannot make SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, asp.net-web-api, grafana-loki

I have a problem trying to log with Grafana Loki from a C# Web API running on IIS:

Windows Server 2012 R2

IIS 6.2

C# .NET 4.7.2

Serilog 2.11.0

Serilog.Sinks.Grafana.Loki 7.1.1

Error message from Serilog diagnostics is:

*2022-07-14T15:55:38.4424139Z Exception while emitting periodic batch from Serilog.Sinks.Grafana.Loki.LokiSink: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Serilog.Sinks.Grafana.Loki.HttpClients.LokiHttpClient.d__1.MoveNext() in /*/src/Serilog.Sinks.Grafana.Loki/HttpClients/LokiHttpClient.cs:line 39
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Serilog.Sinks.Grafana.Loki.LokiSink.d__14.MoveNext() in /*/src/Serilog.Sinks.Grafana.Loki/LokiSink.cs:line 124*

I have tried `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` in the C# code but no luck.

Anyone hit this problem before?

Update: according to their https certificate Grafana only supports TLS 1.3 - is there any way around this?

Comment: Plenty of times. Has 2012 R2 been updated to work with TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3?  Build 6.2 is old and probably won't support TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.

Comment: When Loki started SSL/TSL support? I think clean(without nginx and e.t.c.) Loki work over http.